# how do i colide balls with eachother

Tags: javascript, html, css

how do i colide one ball with anathor

i think its intersection observer that can help but i dont know how to apply it.
i also trid to track all the balls but still no result my knowlage is limited thats why i seek help

help plzz

here is my code for bouncing balls

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    
    
    
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 :root {
  --hue: 200;
  --saturation: 50%;
  --foreground-color: hsl(var(--hue), var(--saturation), 75%);
  --background-color: hsl(var(--hue), var(--saturation), 20%);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
}

.ball {
  --x: 50;
  --y: 50;
  position: absolute;
  /*background-color: var(--foreground-color); */
  background-color: lightgrey;
  left: calc(var(--x) * 1vw);
  top: calc(var(--y) * 1vh);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 2vh;
  height: 2vh;
}
```

script.js

```
const INITIAL_VELOCITY = 0.085
const VELOCITY_CHANGE_RATE = 0
const NUMBER_OF_BALLS = 2


class Ball {
    constructor(ballElem) {
        this.ballElem = ballElem
        this.reset()
    }
    get x() {
        return parseFloat(getComputedStyle(this.ballElem).getPropertyValue("--x"))
    }
    set x(value) {
        this.ballElem.style.setProperty("--x", value)
    }
    get y() {
        return parseFloat(getComputedStyle(this.ballElem).getPropertyValue("--y"))
    }
    set y(value) {
        this.ballElem.style.setProperty("--y", value)
    }
    rect() {
        return this.ballElem.getBoundingClientRect()
    }
    reset() {
        this.x = 50
        this.y = 50
        this.direction = {
            x: 0
        }
        while (Math.abs(this.direction.x) <= 0.1 || Math.abs(this.direction.x) >= 0.9) {
            const heading = randomNumberBetween(0, 2 * Math.PI)
            this.direction = {
                x: Math.cos(heading),
                y: Math.sin(heading)
            }
        }
        this.velocity = INITIAL_VELOCITY
    }
    update(delta) {
        this.x += this.direction.x * this.velocity * delta
        this.y += this.direction.y * this.velocity * delta
        const rect = this.rect()

        if (rect.bottom >= window.innerHeight || rect.top <= 0) {
            this.direction.y *= -1
        }
        if (rect.right >= window.innerWidth || rect.left <= 0) {
            this.direction.x *= -1
        }

        //background color
        // const hue = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue("--hue"));
        // document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--hue", hue + delta * 0.02)
    }
}

function randomNumberBetween(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min
}

var ballarr = []
for (var i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_BALLS; i++) {
    const ballEl = document.createElement('div');
    ballEl.classList.add('ball');
    document.body.appendChild(ballEl);
    const ball = new Ball(ballEl);
    ballarr.push(ball);
}

let lastTime

function updateTime(time) {
    if (lastTime != null) {
        const delta = time - lastTime
        ballarr.forEach(ball => ball.update(delta));
    }
    lastTime = time
    window.requestAnimationFrame(updateTime)

}

updateTime(lastTime);
```

tried many things but still does not work need help

Comment: You need to add some kind of collision detection. You need to loop through your balls and for each you need to check the distance to all other balls. If one of the distances is smaller than the sum of both ball's radius, then they are colliding. Maybe this can help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Tutorials/2D_Breakout_game_pure_JavaScript/Collision_detection